# Changing Ruby versions in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, ruby

I've just installed Ruby 1.9.1 in my Ubuntu 10.10. When I give the command `ruby -v` in terminal, I'm getting "ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]".

I think the older version of Ruby is still there in the PATH. SO, how do I change this to use the new Ruby instead of the old one?

Comment: How did you install it and where did you install it to ?

Answer (score 1):

When Ruby 1.9 is installed from apt it installs as ruby19.  If you really want to use this version you can setup an alias in your ~/.bash_profile, something like:

```
alias ruby='ruby19'
```

This is kind of a hacky solution.  A much better solution would be to run RVM.  It's a ruby manager which allows you to have several versions on Ruby installed and seamlessly switch between them.  It also makes staying up to date much easier.

Installing RVM is really easy to Ubuntu, I've written a short tutorial here: http://blog.dcxn.com/2011/06/20/setting-up-rvm-on-ubuntu-11-04/

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/environment` file to make sure `/usr/local/bin` or whatever path your custom ruby build is in exists. You may also need to logout and log back in to update environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

run `which ruby` to check which one in your path got executed first. But the question is how did you install the 1.9.1?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to have multiple ruby version is to use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/). after installing rvm you can install multiple ruby version simply by

```
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm install jruby
```

switching is even more easy, type (in terminal)

```
rvm use 1.8.7 --default #to use rvm for this terminal session and also sets ruby 1.8.7 as default ruby version
ruby -v #should give ruby version set for current session
ruby use 1.9.2 #sets different ruby to be used for this session
```

for complete installation instruction see [here](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)